# span onClick JQuery change text

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I'm trying to get a value from the database: `SenderDriver->total_trips`.

And all great, but I want to get a specific id so I have to put it into `onClick()`, then it set the value from the database variable: `SenderDriver->total_trips`.

This is the code

```
 <span onclick="readd( amounts{{$referral_detail->SenderDriver->total_trips}});" 
          data-target="#addMoneyModel" data-toggle="modal" id="{{$referral_detail->GetterDriver->id }}">
   <a data-original-title="Add Money" data-toggle="tooltip" id="{{ $referral_detail->GetterDriver->id }}" data-placement="top" class="btn text-white btn-sm btn-success menu-icon btn_detail action_btn"> 
    <i class="fa fa-money-bill"></i> 
   </a>
  </span>
```

Now I want the val to change a specific text when it's clicked using the above code. Btw all this is in .blade.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function readd(){
      $("input:text").val(amounts);
    }
</script>
```

I tried a lot nothing working any help?

The input

```
<div class="modal fade text-left" id="addMoneyModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel33"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <label class="modal-title text-text-bold-600" id="myModalLabel33">@lang('admin.message200')</label>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <form action="{{ route('merchant.AddMoney') }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <label>@lang('admin.message203'): </label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" name="payment_method" id="payment_method" required>
                                <option value="1">@lang('admin.message201')</option>
                                <option value="2">@lang('admin.message202')</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <label>@lang('admin.message204'): </label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="receipt_number" value="0"
                                   class="form-control" required>
                        </div>

                        <label>@lang('admin.message205'): </label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount"
                                   class="form-control" required>
                            <input type="hidden" name="add_money_driver_id" id="add_money_driver_id">
                        </div>

                        <label>@lang('admin.message206'): </label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" id="title1" rows="3" name="description"
                                  value="Refer Gift">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">



                        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal" value="close">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" value="Add">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of `$referral_detail->GetterDriver->id` inside your `readd()` function when the span is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish, but here are my thoughts anyway.

1. In your onclick implementation you provide an argument to the function `readd`, which you're not using/defining in your javascript code at the bottom.
2. It appears that you try to push the value into the input text field of your bootstrap modal with the `id="amount"`

Here is the improved JavaScript section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function readd(amount){
      $("#amount").val(amounts);
    }
</script>
```

I'm not sure if the bootstrap toggle possibly overrides the onclick event of the span element. If that's the case you need to approach that issue a bit different

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function readd(amount){
      $("#amount").val(amounts);
      // Do something with the id
      const some_important_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      console.log(some_important_id);
      $('#addMoneyModel').modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

and remove the modal stuff from your Span element.

```
<span onclick="readd( {{$referral_detail->SenderDriver->total_trips}});" data-id="{{$referral_detail->GetterDriver->id }}">
```

Comment: thank you!
But i need it in span because i need a specific id inside that place so if i put it in function fast i think it will not get the id? i will do what you said anyway thanks! please if you can onclick or something just tell me <3

Comment: it didn't get the value

Comment: What value do you mean?

Comment: this $referral_detail->SenderDriver->total_trips it get the total trips driver make

and it works and get value i want to do it onclick span to set before the popup came because if i did it in the function it get the last id in the table not the specific one

Comment: That's what we are doing there. Sorry that I accidentally left the `amount`keyword in the span onclick event, I removed that, but you need to think a bit for yourself too instead of down-voting my answer

Comment: Thank you i did think and solve it with your create way thank you!

Comment: Bro i didn't down vote its not me i just up vote for you now your 0 i don't know how did that

Comment: Okay, no worries ;-)

Comment: Can you please check?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124906/laravel-1-button-with-2-actions-or-routes